# Создать класс который будет управлять товарами в JS?

Tags: javascript, классы, функции

Я не знаю как создать клас который будет управлять товарами. 
1.  Сортировать по цене. (нужно создать ф-цию)
2.  Сортировать по имени. (нужно создать ф-цию)

я создал коструктор которий создает объекты

```
class Products {
    constructor(name,price,description,img){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.img = img;
    }
}
var nike = new Products("Nike", 100, "new-shoes","img/nike.png");
var adidas = new Products("Adidas", 120, "classic-shoes","img/adidas.png");
var puma = new Products("Puma",150,"new-shoes","img/puma.png");
var jordan = new Products("Jordan", 170, "outlet-shoes", "img/jordan.png");
var converse = new Products("Converse",70,"outlet-shoes","img/convrse.png")
var nikeAirMax = new Products("Nike Air Max", 200, "shoes","img/nikeAirMax.png");
var newBal = new Products("New Balance 990",179,"new-shoes","img/newBal.png");
var arrGoods = [nike,adidas,puma,jordan,nikeAirMax,converse,newBal];
```

Затем создал функцыю которая выводит товары в HTML файл

```
function addGoods(item){
    for (let i = 0; i<arrGoods.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("products").innerHTML += `<div class="info-goods">
            <div class="img"><img src=${item[i].img}></div>
            <div class="name">${item[i].name}</div>
            <div class="price">${item[i].price}</div>
            <div class="description">${item[i].description}</div>
           </div>`
        }
}
addGoods(arrGoods);
```

создал функции которые сортируют (по цене и по имени)

```
function sortByPrise() {
    var div = document.querySelector("#products");
    if (div){
        div.innerHTML = '';
        this.PriseSort(arrGoods);
        addGoods(arrGoods);
    };

}


function sortByName() {
    var div = document.querySelector("#products");
    if (div){
        div.innerHTML = '';
        nameSort(arrGoods);
        addGoods(arrGoods);
    };
}

function PriseSort(arr){
    arr.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.price - b.price;
    });
};

function nameSort(arr){
    arr.sort(function(a,b){
        if(a.name > b.name){
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.name < b.name){
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
};
```

как сделать чтобы фунции эти были в отдельном классе (например class Menedger)

Comment: оберните их в класс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сомневаюсь, что вам нужен отдельный класс для этих целей. Если хочется организовать весь связанный функционал где-то в одном месте, то, быть может, стоит воспользоваться статическими методами. Например

```js
class Product {
  constructor(name, price, description, img) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;
    this.img = img;

    Product.instances.push(this);
  }
}

Product.instances = [];

var nike = new Product("Nike", 100, "new-shoes","img/nike.png");
var adidas = new Product("Adidas", 120, "classic-shoes","img/adidas.png");
var puma = new Product("Puma",150,"new-shoes","img/puma.png");
var jordan = new Product("Jordan", 170, "outlet-shoes", "img/jordan.png");
var converse = new Product("Converse",70,"outlet-shoes","img/convrse.png")
var nikeAirMax = new Product("Nike Air Max", 200, "shoes","img/nikeAirMax.png");
var newBal = new Product("New Balance 990",179,"new-shoes","img/newBal.png");

// var arrGoods = [nike,adidas,puma,jordan,nikeAirMax,converse,newBal];
console.log(Product.instances);
```

Прежде всего обратите внимание на то, что класс `Products` я переименовал в единственное число `Product`, поскольку все-таки объекты при его помощи созданные описывают один продукт, а не несколько. Но это мелочи. Основное - это что сам конструктор теперь имеет свойство `instances`, в которое мы помещаем каждый созданный продукт. При этом также пропадает необходимость в поддержании `arrGoods`.

Функцию, которая выводит товары в HTML тоже можно сделать статическим методом

```js
class Product {
  constructor(name, price, description, img) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;
    this.img = img;

    Product.instances.push(this);
  }
  
  static addGoods() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.instances.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("products").innerHTML += `<div class="info-goods">
            <div class="img"><img src=${this.instances[i].img}></div>
            <div class="name">${this.instances[i].name}</div>
            <div class="price">${this.instances[i].price}</div>
            <div class="description">${this.instances[i].description}</div>
           </div>`
    }
  }
}

Product.instances = [];

var nike = new Product("Nike", 100, "new-shoes","img/nike.png");
var adidas = new Product("Adidas", 120, "classic-shoes","img/adidas.png");

Product.addGoods();
```

```html
<div id="products"></div>
```

Аналогично с функциями сортировки, все делаем статическими методами. Внутри каждого из них все существующие товары будут доступны как `this.instances`.

Comment: Очень большое спасибо. Вы мне помогли. Может вы мне что-то посоветуете (статья, книга может видео которое бы помогло мне в коде такого проекта)? принципы ООП я знаю, просто не знаю как их использовать в настоящих проекта

Comment: @Dmitspit рад помочь :) К сожалению не посоветую ни книг ни видео, не знаю таковых. Практикуйтесь, все придет

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductService {
//Все методы статические
  ProductService.Products = [];

  ProductService.Display = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < Products.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("products").innerHTML += `<div class="info-goods">
            <div class="img"><img src=${Products[i].img}></div>
            <div class="name">${Products[i].name}</div>
            <div class="price">${Products[i].price}</div>
            <div class="description">${Products[i].description}</div>
           </div>`
    }
  }

  ProductService.sortByPrise = function {
    var div = document.querySelector("#products");
    if (div) {
      div.innerHTML = '';
      this.PriseSort(arrGoods); // поменяйте по контектсу
      Display(arrGoods);
    };

  }
  // и т д

}
```

Comment: Мне кажется что даже в общем случае не имеет смысла делать класс с одними лишь статическими полями. Не стоит забывать, что класс в JS - это функция, а какой смысл в функции, которая никогда не вызывается? Для инкапсуляции (неймспейсинга) вполне сгодится объектный литерал.

Comment: @smellyshovel ну пусть не делает статикой...я просто в js ООП не юзаю, поэтому ньюансов не знаю....на другом бы языке я б статикой сделал.

Comment: И, кстати, ваш код синтаксически некорректен.

Comment: Не, так насчет "статики" я с Вами в целом согласен, просто статические поля совершенно не обязательно оборачивать отдельным "классом", вот что я имею в виду.